# Countability and uncountability....

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

Prove or disprove that there are uncountably many disjoint open subset of reals......

According to me, this statement is true... via this a argument.... 
Divide reals into open intervals with consecutive irrationals as the end points.... Then since irrationals are uncountable so are the intervals...and these are disjoint and open too......

I am not sure whether this argument will work or not.... Please cross check it and comment on it....

Further I want to ask whether the same will be true if I replace the set of reals with any uncountable set , or not..... 
Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

The phrase

> consecutive irrationals

is where the problem lies: there **are never** consecutive irrationals! Between any two irrationals we can always find a third. So your intervals can never be constructed in the first place.

---

As to solving the problem, here's a hint: can you think of a *countable* set $S$ of points which hits every open set? If so, what does this imply about any disjoint collection of open sets (given that each one must contain at least one point from the set $S$)?

Comment: Okay... Then whts the correct approach

Comment: @user364168 I've added a hint to solving the whole problem.

Comment: Can u elaborate..... Please....... According to ur hint i can take S to be the set of rationals.....can we..??? And what after that??

Comment: Nd how 'll it be uncountable...??

Comment: @user364168 Yes,take $S$ to be the set of rationals. Now, suppose I have a bunch of disjoint open sets; each one of them has to contain at least one rational - can two of them contain the *same* rational?

Comment: U mean the statement is wrong..... That means there are only countably many disjoint open subset of reals....??

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Or maybe more precisely: there is no uncountable collection of disjoint open sets of reals. Do you see how to prove that, using the fact that the rationals are (i) countable and (ii) dense?

Comment: Okays.... Thanks......

Comment: Now if i consider for eg the set of irrationals....... Can we say the same thing about this set also.... Or not... (subspace topology)

Comment: Yes, it is true in the case of the irrationals as well, by considering them as a subspace of the reals.

Comment: Sorry...... I meant to ask can i say that there are uncountably many disjoint open subsets of irrationals....?? I think this must be true since every singleton irrational as a subset of irrationals will be open..... And there are uncountably many irrationals.....

Comment: "every singleton irrational as a subset of irrationals will be open" Are you sure about that?

Comment: Not sure......but We shall consider the nbd in irrationals only not in reals...... Ryt...?? ...or u can say that the universal set is irrationals....

Comment: @user364168 Remember that an open set in a subspace $S$ is a set of the form $U\cap S$ for some open set $U$ in the original space . . .

Comment: okay thanks.....